# Where can I find the MSMQ Lookup ID before WCF dispatches a message?

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

We have a WCF service hosted in IIS which has a `netMsmqBinding`. Before the message is dispatched to our service, we would like to log the [MSMQ Lookup ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.lookupid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Where I can I find this information?

We get it in an `IErrorHandler` because an `MsmqPoisonMessageException` has a [MessageLookupId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.msmqpoisonmessageexception.messagelookupid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property. We need to log it at the start of a request so we can correlate the exception with the message.

I thought an `IDispatchMessageInspector` would be the right place for this, but I can't seem to find any property in the [AfterReceiveRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that would give me the Lookup ID.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only solution I've found is to use reflection on the Message parameter of `AfterReceiveRequest`. It works, it just seems strange this isn't surfaced as a public property.

```
class MsmqLookupIdBehavior : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    static PropertyInfo lookupIdPropertyInfo;

    static MsmqLookupIdBehavior()
    {
        try
        {
            var type = typeof(MsmqMessageProperty);
            lookupIdPropertyInfo = type.GetProperty("LookupId", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if (lookupIdPropertyInfo != null)
        {
            var lookupIds =
                request.Properties.Values
                .Where(p => p is MsmqMessageProperty)
                .Select(p => lookupIdPropertyInfo.GetValue(p))
                .Where(v => v is long)
                .Select(v => (long)v);

            foreach (var lookupId in lookupIds)
            {
                // Use lookupId here
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // The rest of IDispatchMessageInspector here, not relevant for this behavior
}
```